# How do I use subset in a ggplot pipe?

Tags: r, ggplot2, magrittr

I am trying to use ggplot with subsets to make individually-styled lines for different values of MyName.

This works if I set up the data frame as a temporary variable temp that gets referred to in the subset function like

```
temp <- data.frame(x = ..., y = ..., MyName = ...)
temp %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y= y) + geom_line(data = subset(temp, MyName == "Var Name"), ...)
```

except that I prefer to avoid creating a temporary data frame.

Is there a syntax that allows me to avoid this?
Something like the . in this, except correct:

```
data.frame(x = ..., y = ..., MyName = ...) %>%
%>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y= y) + geom_line(data = subset(., MyName == "Var Name"), ...)
```

This says object '.' not found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use lambda syntax as the `data` argument of a layer. It then knows to use the data supplied to the main ggplot call.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

iris %>% ggplot(aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(data = ~subset(., Species == "setosa"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Some extra details for what happens under the hood; ggplot2 uses the `fortify()` S3 generic on all `data` arguments in the `layer()`  function. There exists a `ggplot2:::fortify.formula()` method that calls `rlang::as_function()`, which replaces the lambda syntax formula with a 'real' function. The `ggplot2:::Layer$layer_data()` ggproto method then calls that function with the plot data as only argument. Note that this is not the same as how the pipe operator works, but a major convenience nonetheless.